# IllegalStateException when adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is called

Tags: android

I have a very simple application. There is a refresh button, everytime it is being clicked, the adapter will call notifyDataSetChanged() to update a ListView. However, I got IllegalStateException all the time. Any quick solution? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Wilson, you might have to give us your code because debugging with that little information won't be easy... Then we might be able to help you

Comment: Isn't button inside ListView?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally figured out the problem. It seems that I used the wrong layout for the ListView.

I used android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2 instead of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1.